# Jsp file fails to iterate over complex elements from a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, parameters, iterator

I'm trying to pass a posts containers from my servlet to the jsp, so I could display all the elements on that jsp page. Every element has time,name and content property. However the jsp file fails to iterate over those elements. How can I fix it?

I have the class:

```
public class post {
public post(long time, String name, String content) {
    super();
    this.time = time;
    this.name= name;
    this.content= content;
}
public String name;
public String content;
public long time;
}
```

and a servlet in which I do:

```
post[] messages;
messages = sortMessages(data); // construct array of post
for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    request.setAttribute("posts", messages[i]);
}
```

In the jsp file I want to display all the posts by the following:

```
<c:forEach var="post" items="${posts}">
    <div class="post">
        <h2>${post.name}</h2>
 <p>${post.content}</p>
</div>
```

however I get an error:

```
root cause
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt;
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:909)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:838)
org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:358)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
serv.viewMessages.doGet(viewMessages.java:122)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


root cause
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt;
org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.toForEachIterator(ForEachSupport.java:274)
org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.supportedTypeForEachIterator(ForEachSupport.java:238)
org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.prepare(ForEachSupport.java:155)
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.doStartTag(LoopTagSupport.java:256)
org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(index_jsp.java:411)
org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:318)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
serv.viewMessages.doGet(viewMessages.java:122)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `items` attribute of `<c:forEach>` expect a collection type object to be able to iterate it. But in your servlet you set the `posts` attribute to a type of `post` object. Instead of setting the `posts` attribute to `messages[i]` just set it to `messages`. And you don't need the for-loop in your servlet.

```
post[] messages;
messages = sortMessages(data); // construct array of post
request.setAttribute("posts", messages);
```

And to enable you to print the attribute of the `post` object in the JSP you need to provide getters methods.

```
public class post {
    public Post(long time, String name, String content) {
        super();
        this.time = time;
        this.name = name;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String name;
    public String content;
    public long time;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public long getTime() {
        return time;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
post[] messages;
messages = sortMessages(data); // construct array of post
for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    request.setAttribute("posts", messages[i]);
}
```

when you are doing `request.setAttribute("posts", messages[i]);` in loop you are just overwritting the previous value. So the "post" will contain only the last value which was supplied in the for loop. Rather you should create a arraylist 
and save the value in the arraylist object and then pass that object to jsp and use jstl there.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        list.add(messages[i]);
    }
      request.setAttribute("posts", list);
```

This way you are sending the list object having all the values, now in jsp you can use this object to get all the values via for loop.

```
<c:forEach var="message" items="${requestScope.posts}">
    <c:out value="${message}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. But how can I access the internal fields of message in that way?

Comment: what is message? its a string array or something else?

Comment: I was missing the getters and setters of that class, thank you

Answer (score 0):

changing it the following way solved the iteratin issue:

```
request.setAttribute("posts", messages);
```

However I can't acces its field and get the error:

```
Property 'name' not found on type serv.post
```